# Combining two time-shifted observables conditionally

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I need to combine two observables which usually produce values one after the other.  The first sequence (let's call it `Seq A`) produces more values than the second (`Seq B`), but usually a bunch of values from the first observable are follewed by one value on the second.  So basically I need to produce a value from the latest value of `Seq A` and the latest of `Seq B`.

However, it can happen that the second sequence doesn't produce a value.  In that case, the combined sequence should still produce a value; when after a value from `SeqA` and some timeout `Seq B` still didn't produce a value, I need to produce a value from just `Seq A`.

The marble diagram should look like this:

```
                          <-> Timeout          No timeout
Seq A  | a1-----------a2a3---------------a4a5-a6---------
Seq B  | --b1----------------------------------b3--------
Output | ---x1--------------x2------------------x3-------
                            ^ - I need this      ^ - And this
```

where `Output` basically is some combination of the values.

PS: I have a hard time explaining the problem consisely, so please excuse the title.

Comment: So, in more layman terms - you want to produce a value from sequence B if sequence A does not produce one fast enough as a failsafe? So A gets a higher priority but if it doesn't yield a value in timeout time then a value from A is chosen?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: almost, but the other way around. B has the priority, A is the fallback.

Comment: There's just not enough specification to warrant tackling this: it's not clear what values of a and b that x is dependent on; it's not clear how a producing subsequent values within the time-out period affects x. I think you are saying that a value from a starts a timeout, upon the expiry of which, or arrival of a b element the latest value of a and the possible b (where b could be no value) are fed into a result-selector to produce x? And at that point the next value of a starts a new timeout? What happens if there is a b and no a - does that b get fed into the result-selector immediately?

Comment: And what about if there are multiple values of a within the timeout period? Will that produce a single output or one for each value of a? Does each value of a trigger a timeout or just the first value following an output event?

Comment: Uh, I accidentially deleted my comment. It was: @JamesWorld: Sorry, I should have provided more information. Given that B produces a value, this value and the last value of A produce the output. But if the timeout occurs, I still need to produce output from A alone. This output is computed using a side-effect that depends on either the fact that A and B have a value or the value of A alone. In case only B delivers, that value is enough to So in essence your assumptions are correct.

Comment: @JamesWorld: Every value of A resets the timeout until it can either be combined with a B value or produces a result without a B. It should behave like using `Sample()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take a stab at this.  Given observables `A` and `B` then I think this will do the trick:

```
// 1500 millisecond timeout to be used on observable B.
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500);

var result =
    A
    .Select(a => 
        B
        .Timeout(timeout)
        .Materialize()
        .Take(1)
        .Select(b => b.Kind == NotificationKind.OnNext ? b.Value : a))
    .Switch();
```

The marble diagram for this should look like this:

```
                                               <-1500ms->Timeout
SeqA   |--------a0--------------a1-a2--------a3---------------------
SeqB   |b0--------b1----b2-----------b3-----------------------------
Output |----------b1-----------------b3------------------a3---------
```

Comment: Perfect, precisely what I needed. Thank you, Sir!